# propel update is behaving as create

Tags: php, orm, frameworks, propel

When I retrieve a record from the db, store it as an object, update it and save it, propel is throwing a validation error because it thinks that I want to create a new record not updating an existing one. Here is an example:

```
    $filter = FiltersQuery::create()->findOneByName("test update DS 2");
 // update it's a field
           $filter->someField("value");
  if ($filter->validate()) {
            $filter->save();
            echo "SUCCESS";
        } else {
            foreach ($filter->getValidationFailures() as $failure) {
                $error_messages .= $failure->getInvalidValue() . " " . $failure->getPropertyPath() . ": " . $failure->getMessage();
            }
            echo $error_messages;
        }
```

I got validation error that is telling me that my object name already exists in the db. But I know that, I'm trying to update not to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

I found what was wrong. The propel validation was is buggy, and is trying to validate the object as a new object not as an updated object. I disabled the validation and now the update is working but without the validation.